# How to add Webpack optimization config in react-app-rewired?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a project that I need to make compatible with IE9.

It turns out IE9 has limits on how many css selectors it supports, hence I am missing part of my styling.

I am bundling my project through create-react-app and yarn build.

Ofcourse, this always gives me a single file.

Tried the following in config-overrides.js

```
const tsImportPluginFactory = require('ts-import-plugin')
const { getLoader } = require('react-app-rewired');
const rewireLess = require('react-app-rewire-less');


module.exports = function override(config, env) {

  const tsLoader = getLoader(
    config.module.rules,
    rule =>
      rule.loader &&
      typeof rule.loader === 'string' &&
      rule.loader.includes('ts-loader')
  );

  tsLoader.options = {
    getCustomTransformers: () => ({
      before: [ tsImportPluginFactory({
        libraryName: 'antd',
        libraryDirectory: 'es',
        style: true,
      }) ]
    })
  };

  config = rewireLess.withLoaderOptions({
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'async',
          minSize: 30000,
          maxSize: 0,
          minChunks: 3,
          maxAsyncRequests: 5,
          maxInitialRequests: 3,
          automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
          name: true,
          cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              priority: -10
            },
            default: {
              minChunks: 2,
              priority: -20,
              reuseExistingChunk: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
  })(config, env);

  return config;
}
```

but no desired result of having multiple css files.

I can't quite figure out, how do I split the build into multiple chunks?